# how to fix data which is passed to paypal api dynamically which refuses to get captured using php

Tags: php, forms, session, paypal

i am working with a paypal api snippet of code.

i am trying to accept payments on my site.

and so by default when i try post the amount to paypal by just declaring in text as below

```
$paypalUrl = $enableSandbox ? 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' : 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

// Product being purchased.
$itemName = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$itemAmount = 20.00;

// Include Functions
require 'functions.php';
```

the amount is correctly posted to the paypal portal

But when i try to pass it dynamically as my project would require in the long run as below

```
$paypalUrl = $enableSandbox ? 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' : 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';


// Product being purchased.
$itemName = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$itemAmount = $_POST['amount'];

// Include Functions
require 'functions.php';
```

The amount is not posted to the paypal portal.

i have even tried saving the amount in a session variable

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['amounts'] = $_POST['amount'];
```

and then trying to access it n the next page which is needed to push it to the paypal portal.

it still does not work

Any idea guys

Comment: Anything from error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: nothing i have just checkd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution around it, for some reason that data was not posted

i created a recordset of information and passed the transactions unique id to the recordset

```
$pos = $_POST['item_number'];
```

/// unique number

```
mysql_select_db($database_emirate, $emirate);
$query_trx = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE transid = '$pos' ORDER BY transid DESC";
```

and now when the transaction needed is pulled according to the above statement, i pass it to paypal like this

```
$itemAmount = $row_trx['amount'];
```